# C#/ClosedXML: problem with reading long numbers as text

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have a table with account numbers in one column and I need to read it. Some of them are read just fine, but some are treated as numbers and either converted into a scientific notation or wrong if I change the format to "0"

For example this dummy account : [image: Account number]

is read as

[image: After changing the format to "@"]

after changing the format to "@".

If I don't change it, it's wrong:

[image: Rounded]

which, obviously is a completely random account number then.

I've searched for and tried out different options, but none is working.
Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Likely they're all being "treated as numbers." It's just that some of them exceed the maximum number of significant digits and thus are expressed in scientific notation. It's hard to be sure without seeing your code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types. Note that a double allows for 15 to 17 significant digits. Your sample has 19.

Comment: You might be able to read it as a `ulong`. That'll give you 19 or 20 significant digits. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types. `decimal` might also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Account numbers aren't real numbers. You're never going to perform mathematical operations on them. You're better off treating them as text. Use `cell.SetValue(value.ToString())`.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to read them as text, but ClosedXml treated them like numbers. I managed to find a solution by parsing the formatted value to decimal.

Comment: What version of ClosedXML?